# Ajax show div if variable is set

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I'm using jQuery to POST some items and save into the database. I have two optional fields, if they're not empty, I'd like to fadeIn in a related div in the success function. You'll notice the `#picCheck.fadeIn`. Right now that fades in if the stuff is submitted, but like I said, I'd like for it fadeIn only if the variable `picvault` from the submitted form has is set.

Here's the jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "edit.php",
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function(){
        $('form#editForm').hide();
        $('div.success').center();
        $('div.success').fadeIn('slow').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 2000).fadeOut(1000);
        $('#picCheck'+sid).fadeIn('slow');
    }
}); // End .ajax function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check the value of picvault in your callback function (assuming it's a checkbox)

```
if($("#picvault").is(":checked")) {
    $('#picCheck'+sid).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The field isn't a checkbox, just a regular textbox. Basically, if we have pictures, we post a link in the textbox to where they're located. If that textbox isn't empty, i'd like to fadein

Comment: Thanks for your help, using your example I was able to use this code to get it working
if ( $("#picvault").val().length > 0 ) {

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the form, just put an if statement around your fadeIn code checking that value.